# Use the Mean Value Theorem to prove that $\sqrt{13} − \sqrt7 <{ 3}/{ \sqrt{7}}.$

Tags: calculus

> Use the Mean Value Theorem to prove that $\sqrt{13} − \sqrt7 < 3\sqrt7.$

So I divided both sides by $(13-7),$ which got me: $$\frac{\sqrt{13}-\sqrt{7}}{13-7}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}},$$ which is closer to MVT.

After this, I am supposed to do $a<c<b$, but I am not sure how to do that and how that will prove the original inequality. Would appreciate Help?

Comment: First what's $a, b$? After that when is $\frac1{2\sqrt x}$ maximal?

Comment: Ya but you are supposed to use the Mean Value theorom. It is required.

Comment: a and b are part of the mean value theorem.

Comment: f(x)=sqrt(x) and a is 7 and b is 13.

Comment: I saw you mentioned Numberphile on a now-deleted post. Numberphile is full of nonsense, and it's impossible to learn proper mathematics from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually,
your question is wrong.
It should be
$\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{7}}
\gt \sqrt{13}-\sqrt{7}
$.

If
$f(x) = \sqrt{x}$
then
$f'(x)
=\dfrac1{2\sqrt{x}}
\gt 0$
for $x > 0$.

By the MVT,
if $a < b$
and $f'(x) \ne 0$,
then
$\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}
=f'(c)
$
where
$a < c < b$.

Using
$f(x) = \sqrt{x}$,
$a = 7, b=13$
we have
$\dfrac{\sqrt{13}-\sqrt{7}}{13-7}
=\dfrac1{2\sqrt{c}}
$
where $7 < c < 13
$.

Therefore
$\sqrt{13}-\sqrt{7}
=\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{c}}
$
where $7 < c < 13
$.

Since $f'(x) > 0$,
$\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{7}}
\gt \sqrt{13}-\sqrt{7}
\gt \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{13}}
$.

Numerically,
$1.133...
\gt 0.959...
\gt 0.832...
$.

Comment: omg, my bad your right. It was $$\frac{3}{\sqrt{7}} $$ instead of $$ 3\sqrt{7}.$$